# Change buttons BackgroundColor using MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have two buttons, When I am clicking on one button I want to change another button `BackgroundColor` using mvvm
I am trying to make it like this

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Red" BackgroundColor="Accent" Command="{Binding ChangeButtons}" x:Name="btnRed"></Button>
    <Button Text="Blue" x:Name="btnBlue"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

When I click on `btnRed` I want `btnBlue` `BackgroundColor` to be changed.
ModelView page

```
public class ButtonColorViewModel
{
    public Command ChangeButtons
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {

               //Change here button background colors

            });
        }
    }
}
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Conform MVVM, you will need one (ore two if you want them to be different) that represents the background color

Comment: I have 3 buttons withing 1 xaml file. on click 1 btn(or the other way around), I need to change another 2 btns bg color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically like this, you need a color property to bind to. You can change the value of the property in your command. You can adjust it to suit your needs,2,3, colors/buttons etc.:

```
public class ButtonColorViewModel
{
    public Command ChangeButtons
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {

               //Change here button background colors
               BackgroundColorBtn1 = Color.Green; //or something
            });
        }
    }


    private _backgroundColorBtn1 = Color.White;
    public Color BackgroundColorBtn1
    {
        get { return _backgroundColorBtn1;}
        set
        {
             if (value == _backgroundColorBtn1)
                 return;

             _backgroundColorBtn1 = value;
             NotifyOnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundColorBtn1));
         }
    }
}
```

With XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Red" BackgroundColor="Accent" Command="{Binding ChangeButtons}" 
            x:Name="btnRed"></Button>
    <Button BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColorBtn1}" Text="Blue" 
            x:Name="btnBlue"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You got me... faster than light :P

Comment: Thank you, nevertheless, please feel free to add information if you want to.

Comment: I'd just say that you could delete `x:Name` as they will keep memory location for nothing, but your answer is perfect

Comment: Hmm, I just remember: doing it like this will invoke `new Command` everytime you push the button....

Comment: Maybe it could be better to create it in the constructor/initializer so the instance will be the same forever and you don't create it every time you click on the button

Comment: Perfect yaar, It's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

The best option, depending on your thought about MVVM, is to avoid (as much as possible) using UI inside ViewModel.
In the previous answer, the color object is used.
If you want to keep MVVM in this case:

- create a property with OnPropertyChanged like maybe an enum
- Bind it to background color button
- Use a converter to convert your property into background color :)

I know it's more stuff but it's more MVVM like.

Also, if you stay only in UI, go to code behind.
Use click and manage the background color directly.

Comment: converter seems difficult to use, as I am  beginner forms. The way you are telling is there any plus?

Comment: Converter is not a big deal and you will see, it's really usefull in WPF :)
But for the moment, continue to explore WPF step by step.

Comment: Along with Converter do I need to use trigger too, to reflect changes, as I seen few wpf question similar to my question on stackoverflow they are using Trigger and I am not sure these things are supporting xamarin.forms as well

Comment: Depends of your goal. Triggers is most likely use to change part of control depends of the state of the control. For exemple if a checkbox is checked, i will change the border,the content and the font color of my checkbox.

Comment: @MatDev8- Thanks for your clarification. I came to know that those things are available in xamarin.forms too.